# ipv6 stopped working, how can I fix it?

Tags: modules, ipv6

I have tried:

```
modprobe ipv6
```

Which returns

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.21-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
```

It has worked until today after I rebooted my pi. I ran an update yesterday which might have caused it.

/lib/modules only contins the following  folders:

- 4.4.38+
- 4.4.38-v7+
- 4.4.43+
- 4.4.43-v7+

Does anyone know how to fix it? I would very much like to be able to resume serving ipv6

Additional info:

- rpi-update = Your firmware is already up to date
- apt-get update/upgrade = No effect
- It might be caused by running the pi off of an external disk. uname -a shows 4.4.21-v7+ Sep 15, but I just updated the firmware today

I got it to work. I not entirely sure how. I think it's because I had a line in fstab:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot/firmware vfat defaults 0 2
```

But I'm not 100% sure so I don't know if I should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

Assuming `ipv6` broke after running `rpi-update` restore from your backup.